# Pasting a formula if value exists in range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that will paste a formula into column I if a value exists in column H.

This piece of code is where I'm having problems.  When I run it, it says `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.`  I know this isn't the most efficient way of accomplishing what I want to do though.  It should only paste that formula if a value exists in column H rather than indiscriminately.  Does anyone know how to do this?

```
Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""Ck #"", G2,"" - "", H2)"
```

---

Full code:

```
Sub prepn()

Columns("I:L").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("I1").Value = "Description"
Range("J1").Value = "Co"
Range("K1").Value = "Au"
Range("L1").Value = "Acct"
Range("M1").Value = "Comments"
Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""Ck #"", G2,"" - "", H2)"
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The formula you are entering is incomplete. There is an open bracket after CONCATENATE, but no closing bracket.

Comment: @GordonK k woops.  fixed now!  the macro still won't work though.

Comment: @pnuts I fixed the closing parenthesis but still come up with the same error even with Sam's fix below.  Any ideas maybe?

Comment: `LastRow` is not declared

Comment: As Slai said - where is your `LastRow` value?

Comment: Your formula is incorrect, what should it look like in the cell?  what are G2 and H2?

Comment: @dwirony I've tried to declare the LastRow value but it seems to come up with another error - I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this though.     Would you happen to know how to paste only if a value exists in Column H?

Comment: @mooseman G2 and H2 have text values in them.  The formula should bring together the values of both cells with the addition of text "Ck #" in front.

Comment: What column do you want the last row to be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think you want.  Last row calc is for column I, the one you are putting data, if not just change the letter

```
  Sub prepn()

    LastRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Columns("I:L").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("I1").Value = "Description"
    Range("J1").Value = "Co"
    Range("K1").Value = "Au"
    Range("L1").Value = "Acct"
    Range("M1").Value = "Comments"
    Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & Chr(34) & "Ck #" & Chr(34) & ", G2," & Chr(34) & " - " & Chr(34) & ", H2)"

End Sub
```

With g2 = Here and H2 = Also
you get This in the cell
=CONCATENATE("Ck #", G2," - ", H2)

I'm betting you don't want G2 and H2 for every cell, but that is another question.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!!! Thank you SO much.  I was searching all over and mashing together code and editing my old code to see what would work and come back to this perfection.  Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely your quotes in the text. They must be written as `""` to result in `"`. Something like this:

```
Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""Ck #"", G2,"" - "", H2)"
```

Comment: Hmm...I did not know that.  I pasted in what you posted directly and it still seems to come up with the same error however. . I'll edit the main post to include my full code in case something is messing it up.  Debug shows that it is that specific line though.

Comment: "" doesn't work in VBA to get a ", Try "=CONCATENATE(" & Chr(34) & "Ck #" & Chr(34) & ", G2," & Chr(34) & " - " & Chr(34) & ", H2)"

Comment: @Sam: Did you try your code?  I did and so did J Doe and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it. It works. Try Debug.Print "\*""\*", which will print \*"\*

Comment: That is 4 quotes in a row, your answer doesn't show that.  I prefer CHR(34) since you don't get problems with "s

Comment: Oh my. That doesn't make it wrong. And yes - my answer shows exactly that. You need two quotes to end up with one.

Comment: I does work now.  Not sure why it didn't before, but you did edit you comment from """" to "*""*", there are differences.